# How to avoid MSR reset after calling system call

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, performancecounter, msr

My purpose is to measure counts of different performance events of particular application using model specific registers (MSRs).

Since, this can be done by using RDMSR and WRMSR at ring 0,I have used Linux module to call these instructions and inserted it using "insmod".

Then I created character device file in /dev directory (mknod) and called it in user mode using ioctl call.

It gives me the correct count, when I use a computational for loop in between two ioctl calls.
However, when I used system("./sample") call instead of loop it gives me wrong values.

```
struct MsrInOut {
        unsigned int op;                            // MsrOperation
        unsigned int ecx;                           // msr identifier
        union {
                struct {
                        unsigned int eax;           // low double word
                        unsigned int edx;           // high double word
                };
                unsigned long long value; // quad word
        };
};
{ MSR_WRITE, 0x186, 0x00410280, 0x00 }, // ia32_perfevtsel1,lcache misses(very important)

ioctl(fd, IOCTL_MSR_CMDS, (long long)msr_start);
system("./sample"); //binary file of same computational for loop 
ioctl(fd, IOCTL_MSR_CMDS, (long long)msr_stop);
```

I read about these calls and know that these calls resets the MSRs. Is there any way to overcome this problem? Or is there any other way to run application inside the C program?

I referred this http://www.mindfruit.co.uk/2012/11/a-linux-kernel-module-for.html.
Please let me know if anyone knows an answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You quite possibly have a bigger problem than that - how do you guarantee that the MSR you write to and the one you read from are even on the same CPU? It's entirely possible your process has been migrated to a different CPU/core/thread in the interim. Some of the MSRs are per-core, others are per-package, ...

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Linux already has support for interfacing with hardware performance counters, including kernel API and userspace tools.  Maybe start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_%28Linux%29